# How do I share a single ADF localization file to multiple google tango tablets?

Tags: android, google-project-tango

How would I easily share a single ADF localization file to multiple google tango tablets? Can it be done all at once for example?

Comment: What you mean by sharing the ADF to multiple devices? you mean through the cloud or just want to use Bluetooth or other methods in real time? one classical offline way is exporting the ADF to sdcard. and pushing to other devices.

Comment: The situation is that we have several tangos and just want to do area learning (make the ADF localization file) for the room once. We are developing on a MAC and not sure how to easily browse for the ADF file and copy it over to other Tango devices. Are there any existing tango utility apps that I can share the same ADF file with all devices? Can it be loaded onto the Tango via something like gmail or bluetooth connection?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is not such utility apps handle what your want.
but all the component are there: Import/Export ADF function in AreaLearning sample code and Bluetooth on android.

you can write them together.
Basically the workflow is:
Record ADF. save it.
Export ADF to sdcard.
Bluetooth connect other devices.
share the ADF to them.
on received devices, import the received ADF.

Classical way for doing Import/Export, can be done through example in Java,C and Unity. since you used Unity. Let's use Unity as a example.

Following the step in developer side:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-codelab-area-learning

and function:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/area-description?hl=pt-BR

Build and run the Unity Examples.
in Unity Examples.

1. Export ADF

Start "AreaDescriptionManagment";granted the "ADF permission".
It will list all the ADF in the Tango API workspace.

Select the ADF you want to export. It will bring you to the new popup.

Click "Export". Grant the Export Permission.It will show where you want to export.default is "/sdcard/"; click Done.
it will export ADF to "/sdcard/"

Use `adb shell ls /sdcard/` 
you will find the UUID of the ADF.

like `de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014`

using `adb pull /sdcard/de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014`
pull the ADF to your linux box or windows folder
using `adb push UUUID /sdcard/`
push the ADF back to your device.

2. Import ADF

same step to "AreaDescriptionManagment".

Click "Import Area Description"
input add uuid to the path.

like: `/sdcard/de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014`
grant the import permission.

The ADF should be in new device's Tango API workspace.

Comment: I'm not sure what location on the tango to import the ADF file to. is it a hidden directory? again, i'm new to android and very new to the tango. From the sample unity code for arealearning, as i understand it, there is a very specific place where all the ADF files are read from in order for unity to use it. is this correct? 

or is there a way to have the unity app successfully read an ADF file located anywhere on the tango device (for example, downloads folder)?

Comment: unity can not directly read any ADF in the tango device.you have to first import those ADF into the API workspace. by using the method I mentioned above.

Comment: I found my ADF in `/sdcard/Maps/`